# How to set Code execute only one time?.

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Project I included a splash-screen.

For that i wrote below code in Login Window Contractor. The Splash Screen is working perfectly. But after login, the main page is opened. if it is closed, then login is opened.

In that the Splash Screen is cross the Login page. I don't want this.

How to do this: Splash Screen Shown only once in my project?

Help me...

```
public LogIn()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Splash));
    th.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    th.Abort();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
} 

private void Splash()
{
    Welcome sp = new Welcome();
    sp.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SplashScreen Splash = new SplashScreen();
    Splash.Show();
}
```

if you want the SplashScreen to close after 3 Seconds then use a timer in the SplashScreen and after 3 Seconds user this.close()

Comment: ok. i am asking about when Second time Login is Opened,.. the Splash also opened. I want to Stop That.

Comment: the Splash Screen want to open at the beginning only. Can u understand my problem?

Comment: Try to use a booelan flag like splashOpened=false and after first show of splashscreen set it to true.   then you just have to put a your splashscreen creation in a if(!splashOpened) and it will only appear one time.

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly pass a boolean parameter which will instruct the Login Constructor to display or not to display the Splash Screen.

```
 public LogIn(boolean splashOpened)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if(!splashOpened) //If Splash Screen is not opened , Open it
        {
            Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Splash));
            th.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            th.Abort();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);           
        }
    } 

    private void Splash()
    {
        Welcome sp = new Welcome();
        sp.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Welcome sp;

public LogIn()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (sp == null)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Splash));
        th.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        th.Abort();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
} 

private void Splash()
{
    if (sp == null)
    {
        sp = new Welcome();
        sp.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```